# how can I get a file, saved using gridform?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, gridfs

I'm using [gridform](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridform) to save a file in gridfs, how can I get the file to return it to a user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution, looking [documentation here](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream#using-with-mongoose)

```
gridfsstream = require('gridform/node_modules/gridfs-stream')
mongoose = require('mongoose')

var conn = mongoose.createConnection(..);
conn.once('open', function () {
  // oid: string representing object id, identifier of a gridfs file
  // res: express response object
  gridfsstream(conn.db, mongoose.mongo).createReadStream(oid).pipe(res);
})
```